# Schedule process not working in Blue Prism

Tags: blueprism

I am trying to schedule process in blue prism which is not working .. nothing happened .. I have searched all the forums not able to find the solutions .. can anyone help me

I went to Schedules -- > New Schedules ---> selected Task ---> provided UTC time to run the process------> 
New Schedule Task--> Drag and dropped the process from Available to resources and Clicked Apply Changes.

Provided UTC time, and tired to change the Local machine time to UTC time zone, I have a Enterprise Licence, tried Run Now option nothing happened

What would be the problem.

Checked the same process from session management and the process running successfully.

Any leads highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a Blue Prism Application Server instance in your environment?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the following :

1. Go to 'System' Tab and then under 'System' option on the left side you should see 'Scheduler'. Make sure that the check box on this screen is checked and it means Scheduler is Active. However, if it is not, you need to tick this check box and restart the resource PC.
2. If 1st is already checked, make sure you run the resource PC with public switch. Because scheduler can only create and run sessions on public resources PC's.

You can acheive it by running 'Automate.exe /public /resourcepc' command.

For additional information on Blue Prism related topic you can refer to

**www.learntoearnit.com**

Let me know if this helps and don't forget to mark the answer correct.

Comment: Thanks Harsh for your explanation , could you please advice should I run the command in CMD prompt ..   'Automate.exe /public /resourcepc' command...could you please explain the second step little bit more .. @Harsh